# Setting up 2 wireless routers, how to extend?

Tags: dd-wrt

I have 2 routers placed in my home, on each side and floor of the house.

Internet access is located on ground floor and is plugged in Router 1 (R1). Router 1 runs a G-radio wireless with WPA2 AES encryption. R1 is also the one dishing out IP to all devices on the network.

Now, Router 2 (R2) is places on first floor and is connected to R1 with cable. Do i need some additional settings besides the default in R1? What mode should R2 run in so i get "roaming" between R1 and R2 so that my computer will choose the best one (but still only see one) network?

R2 should boradcast the same SSID and have the same encryption? R1 is running at channel 1, so I'll set R2 to channel6 then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On R2/R3 you pretty much just have to turn off DHCP, and give them a valid IPs (may want to reserve them on R1. You should not use the WAN port on R2/R3.

You can use the same SSID and stagger the channels 1/6/11.

www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point

Comment: if R1 dish out IPS from 192.168.1.100, i tought i might give it 192.168.1.2 or something. that would do the trick? and same subnet? thanks for the comment on not using the wan, i might just make it a LAN port

Comment: If R1's range is from 192.168.1.1-100, you could give R2 192.168.1.2, and R3 192.168.1.3. Then have DHCP start serving from 192.168.1.4. Or you can reserve R2 & R3's IPs if they are in the DHCP range, because you don't want a client to grab one of their IPs if they happen to lose them for whatever reason.